# jQuery Cycle works on standalone page, but not in WordPress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-cycle

This one makes no sense.  I *was* using jQuery cycle for a featured image slider in WP, but it has stopped working.

Attempting to diagnose what went wrong, I made a simplified version of one of the examples, and it works: http://convoke.info/slide.php

However, if I take the EXACT same markup and copy it into one of my WordPress pages, the plugin doesn't work: http://convoke.info/cycle/

Here's the declaration from my WP header:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://convoke.info/wp-content/themes/convoke2theme/style.css" />
    <!-- include jQuery library -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- include Cycle plugin -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/jquery.cycle.all.latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#featuredslider').cycle({
                fx: 'fade' // choose your transition type, ex: fade, scrollUp, shuffle, etc...
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

And here's where I have the images:

```
<div id="featuredslider">
    <img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach1.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
    <img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach2.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
</div>
```

My only notion as to why this might be happening, and this is just a wild guess, but I recently converted the site in question (Convoke.info) *back* to a single site.  It used to be MU or a network of sites.

Comment: jQuery doesn't appear to be loading correctly. If you go to the JS console and enter `$().jquery` it should return the version number of jQuery. Is there a reason you're using jQuery 1.5? If not try using the latest version instead (1.7.1)

Comment: You are aware you are loading jQuery 1.5 in the header and 1.7.1 at the end of the page, could be an issue there. The `$('#featureslider')` isn't returning anything on your Wordpress page, hence the failure. Try Chrome, hit F12 and use the console to test your jQuery commands.

Comment: In addition to Lazarus's comment, you're also loading the Cycle plugin twice... once in the `head` and again in the `body`.

Comment: Forgive me.  I've modified the header to include jQuery 1.7.1.  I see all those weird scripts loading at the bottom of the page, but I didn't put those there.  My guess is that they're automatically being added at the location of the wp_footer tag for some plugins. I don't know how to disable them...

Unfortunately, I'm pretty useless when it comes to this stuff.  What exactly should I be looking for/testing via the console?

Comment: Hrmmm.... so I removed <?php wp_footer(); ?> from my footer, and that fixed things.  Presumably because it stopped the second instance of jQuery from being loaded (or whatever)  But obviously, I need that tag in there... how can I stop it from automatically loading jQuery in the footer?  I assume it's a plugin dependency?

Comment: In WordPress, you should use the `wp_enqueue_script` to load javascript files. And also, the default object for `jQuery` in this case is `jQuery`, not `$`.

Comment: I'd like to try that, @ViniciusMassuchetto. Do I use `wp_enqueue_scripts` in `functions.php` or do I stick it on my header/page?

Comment: Your header should have a `<?php wp_head(); ?>` call just before the `</head>` tag. Then, you just do a `wp_enqueue_script('jquery')` in a pre-render template file, like `functions.php`. Please take a look at the documentation. You should do this way for every javascript file. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

Comment: Imagine how it would be for every installed plugin to insert its own jQuery `script` tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery in WordPress runs in [no conflict mode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_wrappers). Use instead:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { }
```

Comment: Thank you, but that's a bit too vague for me.  Should the function look like this?

 `<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
   $('#featuredslider').cycle({
    fx: 'fade'
   });
  })'
 </script>`

Comment: Yes, you pass the jQuery object as `$` to your function. Inside, you can use `$` as you are used to. The linked resource has more examples.

Comment: I tried the code from above as well as `<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
   jQuery('#featuredslider').cycle({
    fx: 'fade' // choose your transition type, ex: fade, scrollUp, shuffle, etc...
   });
  })'
 </script>`.  Both stop the slider from working at all, even with `wp_footer()` removed.

Comment: The slider works for me in Opera on your demo page. If you have further questions I suggest to ask on wordpress.stackexchange.com.

Comment: it works now because I have removed wp_footer.  I tried your suggestion (switching `$` for `jQuery`), but that broke it again, so I switched back to the original source using `$`.  I'll try the wordpress stackoverflow.  Thanks.

Comment: Ultimately, this is what worked for me.  I added wp_head and wp_footer back in, and changed the way the function was called as @toscho suggested.  Everything is working fine now.  Thanks!